# How to render a partial html response

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am calling an endpoint as follows in my React project via fetch.

> curl --location 'https://example.com/some/v1' 
> --header 'Content-Type: text/html'

This give me a response like: (It is over 5000 lines, just showing part of it).

```
<style class="ssr-css">
    .some_class {
        margin: 0 auto
    }

    html,
    body {
        overflow-x: hidden;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%
    }
    /* 100+ more styles */
</style>
<style class="ssr-css">
    .some_class_1 {
        margin: 0 auto
    }
    /* 600+ more styles */
</style>
<div class="some_class">
    <div style="color: red" class="some_class_1">
        some text
    </div>
    <!-- 1000's more lines -->
</div>
```

How can I convert this to be a component and render it?

I can't just use dangerouslySetInnerHTML. It will handle the html fine but not the styles.

I could consider something like the following to extract the styles and directly inject to document.

Feels bit hacky and worry this will have side effects on other stylings on my page.

Anyway I could do this using React, without having to directly inject styles to document. A cleaner approach.

Please advice, thanks.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [htmlResponse, setHtmlResponse] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://example.com/some/v1', {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'text/html',
      },
    })
      .then((response) => response.text())
      .then((data) => setHtmlResponse(data))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const styleRegex = /<style\b[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/style>/gm;
    const matches = [...htmlResponse.matchAll(styleRegex)];
    const styles = matches.map((match) => match[1]).join('');

    const styleElement = document.createElement('style');
    styleElement.innerHTML = styles;
    document.head.appendChild(styleElement);
  }, [htmlResponse]);

  return (
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: htmlResponse }} />
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: 5k lines from a request rendered into a single component? Sounds like you might want to redesign what you're trying to do. You can't trust the code coming from the request?

Comment: @Phaelaxz Its from a trusted resource and do need to use this. Are you saying there is an alternate way I could do this without having to convert into a component?

Answer (score 0):

usually what is called an **endpoint** delivers serialised data in JSON for example, not whole HTML documents (cf. https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/rest-api-best-practices-rest-endpoint-design-examples/)

When received, these data are deserialised and then injected in a template (JSX for example with React https://react.dev/learn/writing-markup-with-jsx)
So this should probably be the way to go.

If it would really be more relevant for your need to render a document, then iFrame could be the right choice : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.ASP

Comment: Not sure this is answering the question. We could come around this issue by using dangerouslySetInnerHTML. The issue is that styles are not coming through.